Activate Windows Server 2022 license from cmd
How can I activate a Windows Server 2022 product key from the cmd prompt? I'm not sure if it can be done through CMD or code, and I wanted someone to help me and if it could be done, can someone explain it to me?

Yes, simple using SLMGR via CMD line: slmgr /ipk *key* then:    slmgr /ato to activate it.
You can use slmgr /dlv after to make sure it's activated properly.
For "activate through code" you'd have to be more specific on which language you are wanting to try and use.
